# html break and href in javascript variable (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5

I am trying to set a default message in textarea of form...I want Model name and its link to set in a correct way in textarea....Plus i dont know how can i set the product link(which is in clean_uri) and break points in the javascipt variable....Please help and suggest me a solution.

Format that i want for textarea....

```
Hi, (Website name) has this item that I thought you would really like to know about.                         

 Helena Runolfsdottir                                                      

Click on the link to see more 
Link of Model
```

**Here is my code for textarea in a javascript variable....**

```
var content = "Hi, This website has item that I thought you would really like to know about.{{$cadmodel->name."                                                      "}}"+"Click on the link to see more info."+<a href=clean_uri>Click Here</a>;
```

Comment: And why you tagged this question with PHP?

Comment: I approved it to remove php tag....now happy ??

Comment: use `\n` to make a line break

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen.....and what about clickable link in javascript variable ?

Comment: @ma123456 Yes :) I know it may seems that it isn't that important. You may think "wtf is this kid crying about" ... but look, here on SO people post hunderts of questions every day, and a lot of us has subscribed to only a few tags. For example, I don't know much about Java, C# ... so I haven't subscribed to them. But what I know is PHP. So its quite annoying if you try to help people and then find some questions that has nothing to do with it. Luckly, it doesn't happen that often. But if every user would be as you and wouldn't give a **** about that system, SO would end in a mess.

Comment: @Twinfriends....ok

Answer (score 1):

@ma123456 - Use

```
<div contenteditable="true"  id="txtarea"> </div>


<script type="text/javascript">


    var content = " Hi, (Website name) has this item that I thought you would really like to know about.  <br/>\
                    &nbsp;Helena Runolfsdottir  <br/>\
                    Click on the link to see more \
                    Link of Model\
                   <div contentEditable='false'>  <a href='http://google.com'>Google</a> </div>";

    $("#txtarea").html( content );

</script>
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: If you want to use only textarea you can't do that using html textarea element you should either go for something like https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor

Or go for contenteditable div which will work like textarea

Answer (score 0):

Missing some double quotes. Since its HTML you need to add the link  between quotes as well. Try this:

```
var content = "Hi, This website has item that I thought you would really like to know about.{{$cadmodel->name."                                                      "}}"+"Click on the link to see more info."+ "<a href=clean_uri>Click Here</a> ";
```

if the clean_uri is a variable, try `"<a href=" + clean_uri + ">Click Here</a> "`

Comment: I try it but it is only printing the value of clean uri....not as a link....it showing me like this on my form
<a href=clean uri value here >Click Here</a>

Comment: @ma123456 did you try adding quotes around the clean_uri? since thats a variable it needs to be seen as a variable, add quotes with the plus sign

Comment: clean uri printing the value correctly but not as a clickable link....i want it to work as a clickable link.....if i add quotes around the clean_uri it will not work as a javascript variable...